# store quiz questions in iphone app

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uikit

i am very very new to iphone development so forgive me if its too basic a question. I am working on a quiz app and i need to get the quiz questions from a server and then show them. I have done the retrieving part but i dont know where i can save them because the design of the quiz is such that there are 20 questions and i have to show 4 on each screen, save the user answers and on the last screen, calculate the score and show it to the user. I have just a four day experience of iphone development, so any kind of help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest approach is just to write your data to a plain old file on the file system. If you keep the quiz data as an `NSArray` or something, it can be as easy as:

```
[quizData writeToFile:file atomically:YES]
```

This serializes your array into a format suitable for storing on file and then, well, saves it to the file.

To read it back, you just

```
NSArray *quizData = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:file];
```

To get a suitable file:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *root = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *file = [root stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"quizFile.dat"];
```